# Unable to locate package libvirt-clients error on ubuntu

Tags: openstack, devstack

I am seeing the below error when deploying devstack (openstack) on ubuntu:

E: Unable to locate package libvirt-clients
E: Unable to locate package libvirt-daemon-system

Any clues pls ?

Answer (score 2):

I have this problem too and i use ubuntu trusty
according to this commit:
https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack/commit/03fbc0d71bf4ee85820999ef1324dc319ef9d926?diff=split
they changed the repo packages 5 days ago and just for ubuntu xenial its the same as before : "install_package libvirt-bin libvirt-dev"
but other distros: "install_package libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon-system libvirt-dev"
I think we could better edit the file manually until better changes take place.

Comment: Sorry, not a linux pro here. What's the fix you're suggesting?

Comment: I just switch to Ubuntu 16.0.4 and the installation went through without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to install Devstack it on an unsupported version of Linux. Try Ubuntu 16.0.4 (worked for my today without a single problem) or the one that the [installation guide](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/) says is supported.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt install qemu qemu-kvm virt-manager` for more information check [this](https://github.com/minishift/minishift/issues/2970) out on github.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).